# Write Webtable Values in Excel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to write the webtable values in excel . I tried it with list but its not writing in the correct format.Its writing all the values in the row only.

```
ArrayList<String> Storetablevalues = new ArrayList<String>();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

@BeforeTest
public void setup() throws Exception {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("URL");
}

@Test
public void run() throws Exception {

    /* driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='results']/div/a")).click(); */
    Thread.sleep(9000);
    System.out.println("Values are loaded");
    int Row_count = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='assetsTable']/tbody/tr")).size();
    System.out.println("Number Of Rows = " + Row_count);
    // Get number of columns In table.
    int Col_count = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='assetsTable']/tbody/tr[2]/td")).size();
    System.out.println("Number Of Columns = " + Col_count);
    // divided xpath In three parts to pass Row_count and Col_count values.
    String first_part = "//*[@id='assetsTable']/tbody/tr[";
    String second_part = "]/td[";
    String third_part = "]";

    String[][] arr = new String[Row_count][Col_count]; // Used for loop for
                                                        // number of rows.
    for (int i = 2; i <= Row_count; i++) {
        // Used for loop for number of columns.
        for (int j = 1; j <= Col_count; j++) {
            // Prepared final xpath of specific cell as per values of i and
            // j.
            String final_xpath = first_part + i + second_part + j + third_part;

            // Will retrieve value from located cell and print It.
            String Table_data = driver.findElement(By.xpath(final_xpath)).getText();
            Storetablevalues.add(Table_data);

            System.out.print(Table_data + "  ");

        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
    }

}

public void WriteXL() throws Exception {
    // Write a xl
    try {
        File exlFile = new File("C:/Users/Kishor/Desktop/gtmetrix.xls");
        WritableWorkbook writableWorkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(exlFile);
        WritableSheet writableSheet = writableWorkbook.createSheet("Sheet2", 0);
        Label Header_Url_label = new Label(0, 0, "URL");
        Label Header_Image_label = new Label(1, 0, "Link Check Status");

        writableSheet.addCell(Header_Url_label);
        writableSheet.addCell(Header_Image_label);

        for (int i = 0; i < Storetablevalues.size(); i++) {
            int j = i + 1;
            Label labelURL = new Label(0, j, Storetablevalues.get(i));
            writableSheet.addCell(labelURL);
        }

        // Write and close the workbook
        writableWorkbook.write();
        writableWorkbook.close();
        System.out.println("Xls Writer...");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RowsExceededException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (WriteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}
[This is my console Output I want to write in this format in excle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWXtg.png)

Comment: This [link](http://www.guru99.com/all-about-excel-in-selenium-poi-jxl.html) might be help full to read and write Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class TableToExcel {

    String[][] tableVal;
    int rowCount,columnCount;
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "C:/MyFirstExcel.xls";
    //https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro
    @BeforeClass
    public void getTableSize(){
        driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro");
        driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");
        //get Row size
        List<WebElement> row =  driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table/tbody/tr"));
        //get Column size
        List<WebElement> column = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table/tbody/tr/th"));
        rowCount = row.size();
        columnCount = column.size();
        System.out.println("Row :"+rowCount+" Clounm :"+columnCount);
        tableVal = new String[rowCount][columnCount];
    }
    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException{
        for(int i =1 ; i <= rowCount ; i++ ){
            for(int j =1 ; j <= columnCount ; j++ ) {
                if(i == 1) {
                    //Get header value
                    tableVal[i - 1][j - 1] = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/th[" + j + "]")).getText();
                    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/th[" + j + "]")).getText());
                }
                else{
                    //get table data values
                    tableVal[i-1][j-1] =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText();
                    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")).getText());
                }
            }
            }
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Datatypes in Java");

        int rowNum = 0;
        System.out.println("Creating excel");

        for (Object[] datatype : tableVal) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            int colNum = 0;
            for (Object field : datatype) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
                if (field instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
            workbook.write(outputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            workbook.close();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```